# JDBC - can cassandra sparksql connector do joins in query tool ie Tableau/Alteryx/Sqlclient?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, spark-cassandra-connector

With SparkSQL Cassandra connector can a JDBC client tool (ie DBVisualizer, Tableau, Alteryx.etc) join 2 cassandra tables with SparkSQL?

All documentation I see refers to joinWithCassandraTable (which I assume only works in scala/java code or spark-shell but not a standard SQL client)
https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector

Comment: cc @user:2517180

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DSE should support this if you're using JDBC driver that is available from DataStax Academy Downloads page. You'll need to run the Spark SQL Thrift server (via `dse spark-sql-thriftserver` command)...  If you're just starting, DSE 6 has more improvements around this part (so-called Always On SQL Service (AOSS)).

[Here is the old blog post](https://www.datastax.com/2015/03/how-to-do-joins-in-apache-cassandra-and-datastax-enterprise) that talks about ODBC driver + Spark SQL and joins, but the same should be for JDBC drivers.

Comment: Datastax downloads page has Simba JDBC driver, tried a join but nothing returned :( Even self-join to same table 0 rows!